# MySQL INTERSECT replacement INNER JOIN - Please explain

Tags: mysql

I have been messing around with this for a while and cannot seem to figure out how to convert the following code from INTERSECT form (unsupported by MySQL) to INNER JOIN form.

If someone could convert the following code to INNER JOIN I think I could understand from the example. Thanks in advance!

```
(SELECT Student.SSN, First_Name, Last_Name 
FROM Student, Enrolls 
WHERE Enrolls.SSN = Student.SSN AND CourseNo='CSC132')

INTERSECT

(SELECT Student.SSN, First_Name, Last_Name 
FROM Student, Enrolls 
WHERE Enrolls.SSN = Student.SSN AND CourseNo='CSC134');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quassnoi's answer pre-supposes a **lot** about the structure of the data. The following is more robust (and possibly more efficient):

```
 SELECT  s.SSN, s.First_Name, s.Last_Name 
 FROM    Student s,
         Enrolls e1,
         Enrolls e2
 WHERE e1.SSN=s.SSN
 AND   e2.SSN=s.SSN
 AND   e2.SSN=e1.SSN
 AND   e1.CourseNo='CSC132'
 AND   e2.CourseNo='CSC134';
```

Comment: A more standard approach, but quicker indeed!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  SSN, First_Name, Last_Name 
FROM    student s
WHERE   (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    enrolls e
        WHERE   e.ssn = s.ssn
                AND e.courseNo IN ('CSC132', 'CSC134')
        ) = 2
```

I'm hoping you're not really using `SSN` are a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: This is just for learning purposes at the moment, however couldn't I use it as PRIMARY KEY if it were somehow encrypted?

Comment: @Dennis: it's not about encryption, it's about uniqueness and generality. Don't know about your law requirements but what if a student does not have an `SSN`? What if two students have the same one?

Comment: Good point - however in US SSN is unique and all citizens must have one. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Dennis: according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number, it is neither unique nor mandatory for `US` citizens. But again, I'm not even a `US` resident to judge. It's that every database book gives an example of `SSN` as of a bad `PRIMARY KEY`, so I thought I'd warn you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to do like this

```
SELECT Student.SSN, First_Name, Last_Name FROM

(SELECT Student.SSN, First_Name, Last_Name 
FROM Student, Enrolls 
WHERE Enrolls.SSN = Student.SSN AND CourseNo='CSC132') AS a

INNER JOIN

(SELECT Student.SSN, First_Name, Last_Name 
FROM Student, Enrolls 
WHERE Enrolls.SSN = Student.SSN AND CourseNo='CSC134') AS b

USING (Student.SSN, First_Name, Last_Name)
```